# Alert box does not work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bootbox

I am trying to display an alert box and click on Ok to refresh the page. I have tried using `window.location.reload(true)`

I want to show a message before page reload. The problem is that the page reloads automatic but the alert box not showing.

**HTML Content**

```
<form action="<?php echo $action_link; ?>" method="post" name="form_Change_Password" id="form_Change_Password" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate">

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $admin_id; ?>">
        <div class="form-body">
            <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> You have some form errors. Please check below. 
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success display-hide">
                <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> Your form validation is successful! 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group  margin-top-20">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Old Password
                    <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-icon right">
                        <i class="fa"></i>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="old_password" id="old_password" value=""> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">New Password
                    <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-icon right">
                        <i class="fa"></i>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" id="new_password" value=""> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Confirm Password
                    <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-icon right">
                        <i class="fa"></i>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" value=""> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                    <button type="button" class="btn green" name="btnChangePassword" onclick="newpassword(<?php echo $admin_id; ?>)">Update</button>
                    <a href="<?php echo $admin_url; ?>index.php?file=a-admin_profile" class="btn default">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Ajax Code:**

```
$.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo $action_link; ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'id': <?php echo $admin_id; ?>,
                'old_pass': old_pass,
                'new_pass': new_pass,
                'conf_pass': conf_pass,
                change_password : 'change_password'
            },
            success: function (result){
                if(result == 1){
                    bootbox.alert('Password changed successfully.');
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }else if(result == 2){
                    bootbox.alert('New password and confirm password does not match.');
                    return false;
                }
                else if(result == 0){
                    bootbox.alert('Old password does not match.');
                }
            },
            error: function (result){
            }
        });
```

**Action**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['change_password']) && $_REQUEST['change_password'] == 'change_password'){

    ob_get_clean();
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->CONN,md5($_REQUEST['old_pass']));

    $dbpassword = $admin->select_password($id);

    $newpass = $_REQUEST['new_pass'];
    $confpass = $_REQUEST['conf_pass'];

    if($dbpassword != $password){
        echo 0; exit;
    }elseif($newpass != $confpass){
        echo 2; exit;
    }
    else{
        $admin->update_password($id, md5($newpass), $current_date);
        echo 1; exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use **[`bootbox callback`](http://bootboxjs.com/#gist4340138)** :

```
bootbox.alert("Password changed successfully.", function() {
    // any code you want to happen after the alert is dismissed
   window.location.reload(true);
});
```

So it will be :

```
...
success: function (result){
    if(result == 1){
        bootbox.alert("Password changed successfully.", function() {
            window.location.reload(true);
        });
    }else if(result == 2){
        bootbox.alert("New password and confirm password does not match.", function() {
            return false;
        });
    }else if(result == 0){
         bootbox.alert('Old password does not match.');
    }
},
...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the following:

```
bootbox.alert('Password changed successfully.', function(){
    window.location.reload(true);
});
```

Instead of:

```
bootbox.alert('Password changed successfully.');
window.location.reload(true);
```